# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed. in vb.net please help me

Tags: vb.net

Again error in code. Please help me.

```
'Private Sub btn_Issue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Issue.Click
        Dim con111 As New OleDbConnection
        con111.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\library.mdb"
        Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM NormalTransaction WHERE BarCodeNo=@barcode"
        Dim cmd11 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(theQuery, con111)
        cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", txt_BarcodeNo.Text)


        Using reader11 As OleDbDataReader = cmd11.ExecuteReader()

            If reader11.HasRows Then
                ' Book Already Exists
                MsgBox("Book Already Exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "SIMS Library")
            Else
                ' User does not exist, add them
                Dim cmd12 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

                If Not con111.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con111.Open()
                End If    

                cmd12.Connection = con111    

                cmd12.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NormalTransaction([RegNo],[Name],[MemType],[Department],[BarCodeNo],[Title],[Author],[AccNo],[BookType],[CallNo],[Subject],[IssueDate],[DueDate]) VALUES (@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13)"
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", txt_RegisterNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", txt_Name.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", txt_MemberType.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", txt_Department.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", txt_BarcodeNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", txt_Title.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", txt_Author.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", txt_Accession.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a9", txt_BookType.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a10", txt_CallNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a11", txt_Subject.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a12", DateTimePicker1.Value)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a13", DateTimePicker2.Value)

                cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery()

                con111.Close()

                MsgBox("Records Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Customer!")

            End If
        End Using

        con111.Close()
    End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply opening the connection too late, it needs to be opened before ExecuteReader-call:

```
'Private Sub btn_Issue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Issue.Click
        Dim con111 As New OleDbConnection
        con111.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\library.mdb"
        Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM NormalTransaction WHERE BarCodeNo=@barcode"
        Dim cmd11 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(theQuery, con111)
        cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", txt_BarcodeNo.Text)

        con111.Open()

        Using reader11 As OleDbDataReader = cmd11.ExecuteReader()

            If reader11.HasRows Then
                ' Book Already Exists
                MsgBox("Book Already Exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "SIMS Library")
            Else
                ' User does not exist, add them
                Dim cmd12 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

                cmd12.Connection = con111    

                cmd12.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NormalTransaction([RegNo],[Name],[MemType],[Department],[BarCodeNo],[Title],[Author],[AccNo],[BookType],[CallNo],[Subject],[IssueDate],[DueDate]) VALUES (@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13)"
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", txt_RegisterNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", txt_Name.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", txt_MemberType.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", txt_Department.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", txt_BarcodeNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", txt_Title.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", txt_Author.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", txt_Accession.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a9", txt_BookType.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a10", txt_CallNo.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a11", txt_Subject.Text)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a12", DateTimePicker1.Value)
                cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a13", DateTimePicker2.Value)

                cmd12.ExecuteNonQuery()

                con111.Close()

                MsgBox("Records Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Customer!")

            End If
        End Using

        con111.Close()
    End Sub'
```

Comment: Now new error comes datatype mismatch in criteria expression.. Only BarCodeNo is Number , datetimepicker1,datetimepicker2 is date rest of everything text

Comment: If barcodeno is a number, pass it as a numeric parameter cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", Convert.ToInt32(txt_BarcodeNo.Text))

Comment: Check the data types of your variables and the data types in your database that they match. And the order of the parameters in your sql query, that it is the same order you add the paramters to the oledbcommand. Something is not right if you get that error, i can't help you more.